# Degraded 2D performance when there is no CPU/GPU load

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, performance

My VGA used to be GTX 1080, but it died. And I started to have this issue after its replacement with an older GTX 760.

The issue is a degraded 2D performance when there is no load on the system.
e.g. typing/selecting text in sublime is laggy. The animations during minimizing/maximizing firefox/terminal are not smooth, etc.

Two things which I've tried and **do not work** are:

1) Reinstalling the VGA driver with the following commands:

```
nvidia-installer --uninstall
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

This installs the 440.82 driver version

2) Setting "Prefer Maximum Performance" from the NVIDIA driver settings (NVIDIA X Server).

The only thing that works for now and fixes the issue is to start a `dota2` client and just leave it to run in the background.

The rest of my setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with 4.15.0-101-generic
- Ryzen 3600X with B450 and AGESA 1.0.0.4B, 16GB RAM
- Dual monitor setup